# How could I set a value on edittext

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext, layout-inflater

is it possible to set a value into a editable edittext like this?

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt_dialog, null);

    final EditText input = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.input_prompt);
    TextView txt_prompt_mensaje = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.txt_prompt_mensaje);

    Editable value = input.getText();

    int suma_valor = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
    suma_valor = suma_valor + Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
    Log.d("#### suma valor", Integer.toString(suma_valor));
    input.setText(Integer.toString(suma_valor));
```

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what did you observe?

Comment: the setText method does not reflect changes

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to multiply a preset number by 2.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: increment the value by number input value

Comment: Are you getting any errors in `LogCat`? Also, why is input `final`?

Comment: my bad, input shouldnt be final, and no, I'm not getting any errors in Logcat

Comment: i dont know why input.setText method  does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `input.setText("Testing");` will give the editText the string of "Testing" in it's field. However you question seems vague when you say 'set a value'.
Another thing to add is that the editText will only take the values for when it is first instantiated.

Comment: yeah, i need setting a value in the input edittext but this editext is on layout that i inflate into the main layout, so why i cant settext easily like always we do??

Comment: what does you Log.d give...?
Because it looks like you are just using an empty field to do some calculations, then assigning the empty answer to input